# DIY Cable For Keyboard: USB type C to USB Type A question

Tags: usb

I am trying to make a cable for my keyboard, but am confused about the different types of Type C connectors you can get.  As an example, [this ad on Ali Express](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002253691833.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.34182df88Tablr&algo_pvid=c9d78aad-1296-4082-b971-936f514e2d12&algo_exp_id=c9d78aad-1296-4082-b971-936f514e2d12-12&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000019662293250%22%7D) lists different types - Would the 2A Charging and Data one be OK? It doesn't specifically list what pull down resistors it uses or anything. How would I know?  Thanks.

Comment: Try looking for information on the connectors from sources other than a shopping site. e.g. [usb.org](https://usb.org/) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#Connectors)